# Flask-Security @roles_accepted not working. Why isn't g.identity providing the roles granted to the user?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, flask, authorization

I'm trying to get roles to work with Flask-Security, but even though `current_user` has the roles I expect, `g.identity` does not provide them `<Identity id="..." auth_type="None" provides=set([])>`, and `@roles_accepted` refuses access.

The function `_on_identity_loaded` in core.py is never called, and I guess that's part of the mystery. I'm running the server in unit tests via the `app.Flask.test_client()`.

I first made a small experiment based on the MongoEngine based tutorial on the Flask-Security site, and that worked when I played around with it. I haven't worked test-driven with that, so I don't know if that would also fail with `test_client()`.

Since we're using MongoKit instead of MongoEngine, and using Flask for a REST service, I've had to supplement Flask-Security with a bit more code than I hoped...

This part works, so I think my User class is providing the roles correctly:

```
u = api_security.user_datastore.find_user(email=u'admin')
r = api_security.user_datastore.find_role(u'admin')
api_security.user_datastore.add_role_to_user(u, r)
assert r in u.roles
```

I have implemented `__eq__` and `__ne__` using comparison on the mongo _id, so I'm not relying on object identity for the assert above.

I'm logging in and logging out with different identities, and the decorator `@login_required` works as intended. It all runs the same if I put `assert 0` in `core._on_identity_loaded`, so that function is never called. I assume this is the function that's supposed to populate the Identity with UserNeed (a.k.a. roles?) so it makes sense that it doesn't work... But why isn't it called?

I'm running as below in Python 2.7.6 on OS X 10.10.2.

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Login==0.2.11
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Principal==0.4.0
Flask-RESTful==0.3.2
Flask-Security==1.7.4
Flask-WTF==0.11
mongokit==0.9.1.1
pymongo==2.8
Werkzeug==0.10.1
WTForms==2.0.2
```

Comment: I made a small REST client, so that I could test the server without relying on the test_client(). Same result. @roles_accepted still refuses access even though the user has the needed role.

Comment: I've revisited my initial experiment, and @roles_accepted still works as expected there. So, my MongoKit adapter for Flask-Security is not the culprit it seems. The main differences between the experiment and my later (failing) attempt is that the problem code uses blueprints, and provide a REST API instead of HTML templates.

Comment: I'm exploring using Flask-Security in a project that uses MongoKit instead of MongoEngine. Based on your experience, is this feasible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Even that roles were correctly resolved for a user, the function `flask_security.core._on_identity_loaded` was not called and therefore identity didn't have appropriate persmissions.

The reason was that `Security` was initialized using `flask.current_app` instead of a simple `app` object. This breaks the signaling mechanism inside the `flask_security` module.

The solution is to initialize the `Security` either using simple `app` object

```
Security(app, datastore)
```

or getting that object from `current_app`

```
Security(current_app._get_current_object(), datastore)
```